# Statement of Artin Reciprocity by Silverman

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I have a seemingly easy question concerning the Artin Reciprocity as stated in the book *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* by Silverman. He states it as follows.

*Let $L/K$ be a finite abelian extension of number fields. There exists an integral ideal $\mathfrak{c} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$, divisible by precisely the primes of $K$ that ramify in $L$, such that
    \begin{align*}
  (\alpha \mathcal{O}_K , L/K) = 1 \;\;\; \textit{for all $\alpha \in K^{\times}$ satisfying $\alpha \equiv 1 \;(mod\; \mathfrak{c})$}. 
 \end{align*}*
Here $(\; \cdot \;, L/K)$ denotes the Artin map $I_K(\mathfrak{c}) \longrightarrow \text{Gal}(L/K)$, where $I_K(\mathfrak{c})$ is the group of fractional ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ which are relatively prime to $\mathfrak{c}$. First of all, I am unsure about what the congruence means, since $\alpha$ does not necessarily belong to $\mathcal{O}_K$. Moreover, I wonder why it makes sense to evaluate the Artin map at $\alpha \mathcal{O}_K$, i.e. why none of the primes in the factorization of $\alpha \mathcal{O}_K$ appears in the one of $\mathfrak{c}$...

Thanks in advance for any comment.

**UPDATE:** By consulting *Algebraic Number Theory* by Lang, Chapter VI, the question on the special congruence got solved and with it the problem on evaluating the Artin map.

Comment: For each  prime ideal $P \in O_K$ factorize $PO_L = \prod_j Q_j^e$, restrict to the case  $e=1$ (unramified),  let $\sigma = (Q_j,L/K)=(P,L/K)\in Gal(L/K)$ such that $\forall a \in O_L, a^{N(P)}-\sigma(a) \in Q_j$. For each $a \in O_K-0$, factorize $(a) = \prod_l P_l^{d_l}$, if the $P_l$ are unramified let $((a),L/K) = \prod_l (P_l,L/K)^{d_l}$, since $Gal(L/K)$ is abelian it is well-defined. Let $H = \{ a \in O_K-0, ((a),L/K) = 1\}$. Artin reciprocity : $H$ contains $1+ d O_K$ for some $d$. From there you have a simple description of the Artin map in term of congruences and the class group.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But to me it seems that this is not quite what is of interest for me at the moment (or I misunderstand your point). At this moment I do not want to have a different description of the Artin map or the statement, I just want to understand this specific statement made by Silverman. However, this confusion is now clarified for me.

Comment: It is not a different description, it is a simpler and concrete one. The whole theorem is about constructing $d$, relating it to the ramified primes, and the exact quotient of $I_K$ by $\ker( (.,L/K))$.

Comment: I do not fully understand this description (e.g. why does it only include elements of the ring of integers and their integral ideals and not non-zero elements of $K$ and their fractional ideals), but I will think about it again, thanks for pointing this out!